# MSP430 use DMA to transfer float var stored in RAM

Tags: floating-point, ram, msp430, dma

I will try to be more clear as possible:
I need to transfer 3 float var calculated in RAM memory into a Buffer stored in a different location in RAM memory: I wrote a code to do that but the buffer isn´t filled in the right way: I can read only one value. This is the function in RAM that calculates the var

```
#pragma CODE_SECTION(Calculatevar,".FLASHCODE")
void Calculatevar(volatile signed char *a,volatile signed char *b,volatile signed char *c)
{
float axg, ayg, azg; // x, y, and z axis readings of the accelerometer
volatile unsigned char a_x,a_y,a_z;

axg = (ax + 2083)/16131.0;
ayg = (ay + 208)/16131.0;
azg = (az + 204)/16131.0;

*a=axg*126;
*b=ayg*126;
*c=azg*126;
}
```

in main() I wrote Calculatevar(&a,&b,&c); defining  volatile signed char a,b,c;
Here is the DMA function:

```
   unsigned char DMA_transfer(buffer *pointer_buffer) //DATA WRITE/PUSH
{ int next = pointer_buffer->head + 1;
   if (next >= pointer_buffer->Num_Samples)
    next = 0;
   //buffer is full
    DMA0SZ =pointer_buffer->Num_Samples;
//    __data20_write_long((unsigned long) &DMA0SA,(unsigned long) &d1);
    __data20_write_long((unsigned long) &DMA0SA,(unsigned long) & a);
    __data20_write_long((unsigned long) &DMA0DA,(unsigned long) &pointer_buffer->buffer[pointer_buffer->head]);
    DMA0CTL |= DMAEN +DMAIE;                         // Enable DMA0
    DMA0CTL |= DMAREQ;                      // Trigger block transfer
    pointer_buffer->head = next;
    return 0;
}
```

What I am missing??

Comment: What is `a`? What is `Num_Samples`?

Comment: a is one of the var that I need to get while Num_samples is the number of char stored in the buffer defined as:

`typedef struct
{
 volatile signed char * const buffer;
    int head;
    int tail;
    const int Num_Samples;
}buffer;`

Comment: Show the definition of `a`.

Comment: a,b,c are defined as `volatile signed char a,b,c; ` as a global var

Comment: What are the addresses of `a`, `b`, and `c`? (Look into the map file.)

Comment: I decided to avoid float points arithmetic switching to signed char. I still get problem during data communication...but I think that now it is an off-Topic since it is not so close to the initial question. Anyway the address are a=0x001C25 b=0x001C26 c=0x001C27

Comment: Does it work with `char`s?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the first snippet has no relation to the DMA, and shows 3 chars being stored instead of floats.

Secondly, there is no code setting up block transfers, source/destination address change or byte (versus word) transfers.

If there is no other code configuring DMA0, the default single transfer mode of one word would account for only one value being correctly transfered, since neither source nor destination addresses are incremented after each of the DMA0SZ number of transfers.